# Clearing Chrome cache in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a Razor view in my asp.net MVC 3 application. It is a page where I fill Payment info. After I signout, I try to purchase another product. When I click any one the textboxes, I get dropdown showing what I filld earlier. How can I clear the cache for this page ? This happens in chrome only.

Comment: This is not a programming question; this is a question about Chrome's cache. I think you'll find that this will happen on any website unless you change Chrome's settings.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It is a programming question, but "cache" doesn't really describe the problem, nor is it browser specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare your textboxes, you need to add `autocomplete="off"` to your attribute collection, it will work for most browsers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag) for more information.